# Change callback function on the fly

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

A component excepts a callback function to execute it on certain event.
E.g.

```
    var actions = [
        {
            event: 'click',
            cb: function () {
                app.router.navigateTo('bonus/claim');
            }
        },
        {
            event: 'click',
            cb: function () {
                app.router.navigateTo('bonus/overview');
            }
        }
    ];
    var component = new Component({actions: actions});
```

In the component the cb is registered like this

```
    for (var i = 0, l = actions.length; i < l; i++) {
         self['someFunctionName'] = actions[i].cb;
    }
```

Based on settings I may need to augment the `cb` function by adding additional functionality. E.g. `this.trigger('someEvent');`

so that the `cb` looks like this:

```
   function () {
        this.trigger('someEvent');
        app.router.navigateTo('bonus/overview');
      }
```

What is the best way to do it?